# Improving distinct values estimates in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, distinct, cardinality-estimates

Full counts in Postgres can be slow, for reasons that are well-understood and much discussed. So, I've been using estimation techniques instead, where possible. For rows, pg_stats seems fine, for views, extracting an estimate returned by `EXPLAIN` works okay.

https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/count-made-fast/

But what about distinct values? Here, I have had a lot less luck. Sometimes the estimates are 100% correct, sometimes they're off by factors of 2 or 20. Truncated tables seem to have badly stale estimates in particular (?).

I just ran this test and have provided some results:

```
analyze assembly_prods; -- Doing an ANLYZE to give pg_stats every help.

select 'count(*) distinct' as method,
        count(*) as count
from (select distinct assembly_id 
      from assembly_prods) d 
union all
select 'n_distinct from pg_stats' as method,
        n_distinct as count
from pg_stats 
where tablename  = 'assembly_prods' and
      attname    = 'assembly_id';
```

The results:

```
method                      count
count(*) distinct           28088
n_distinct from pg_stats    13805
```

That's only off by a factor of 2, but I've seem *much* worse in my data. To the point where I won't use estimates. Is there something else that I can try? Is this something that PG 12 improves?

## Follow-up

I hadn't ever experimented `SET STATISTICS` before, because there are only so many hours in a day. Inspired by Laurenz' answer, I've take a quick look. Here's a useful comment from the documentation:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/planner-stats.html

> The amount of information stored in `pg_statistic` by `ANALYZE`, in
>   particular the maximum number of entries in the `most_common_vals` and
>   histogram_bounds arrays for each column, can be set on a
>   column-by-column basis using the `ALTER TABLE SET STATISTICS` command,
>   or globally by setting the `default_statistics_target` configuration
>   variable. The default limit is presently 100 entries. Raising the
>   limit might allow more accurate planner estimates to be made,
>   particularly for columns with irregular data distributions, at the
>   price of consuming more space in `pg_statistic` and slightly more time
>   to compute the estimates. Conversely, a lower limit might be
>   sufficient for columns with simple data distributions.

I have often got tables with a few common values and a lot of rare values. Or the other way around, so the right threshold will depend. For those who haven't used `SET STATISTICS`, it lets you set the sampling rate as a target number of entries. The default is 100, so 1000 should be higher fidelity. Here's what that looks like:

```
ALTER TABLE assembly_prods 
    ALTER COLUMN assembly_id
    SET STATISTICS 1000;
```

You can use `SET STATISTICS` on a table or index. Here's an interesting piece on indexes:

https://akorotkov.github.io/blog/2017/05/31/alter-index-weird/

Note that the current documentation *does* list `SET STATISTICS` on indexes.

So I tried out thresholds of 1, 10, 100, 1000, and 10,000 and got these results out of a table with 467,767 rows and 28,088 distinct values:

```
Target   Estimate  Difference  Missing
     1   13,657    14,431      51%
    10   13,867    14,221      51%
   100   13,759    14,329      51%
 1,000   24,746     3,342      12%
10,000   28,088         0       0%
```

Obviously you can't draw any general conclusions from one case, but `SET STATISTICS` looks pretty darn useful and I'll be glad to have it in the back of my mind. I'm tempted to raise the target a bit in general as I suspect it would help in many of the cases in our system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, a remark: your query could be written simpler as

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT assembly_id) FROM assembly_prods;
```

Also, your statistics query is wrong, because `n_distict` can also be negative. You should query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN s.n_distinct < 0
            THEN - s.n_distinct * t.reltuples
            ELSE s.n_distinct
       END AS n_distinct
FROM pg_class t
   JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = t.relnamespace
   JOIN pg_stats s ON t.relname = s.tablename
                      AND n.nspname = s.schemaname
WHERE s.schemaname = 'public'
  AND s.tablename = 'assembly_prods'
  AND s.attname = 'assembly_id';
```

For a simple query like that, the statistics should contain a good estimate.

If the estimates are off, try to `ANALYZE` the table. That will also fix the results for a newly `TRUNCATE`d table. `TRUNCATE` does not cause PostgreSQL to autoanalyze the table (there may be room for improvement here).

If that improves the results, see that the table is analyzed more often by configuring

```
ALTER TABLE assembly_prods SET (autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.05);
```

It is also possible to set `autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor` to 0 and raise `autovacuum_analyze_threshold` to the daily change rate for the table.

If `ANALYZE` alone does not improve the estimate, increase the size of the sample:

```
ALTER TABLE assembly_prods ALTER assembly_id SET STATISTICS 1000;
```

A new `ANALYZE` should now produce better estimates.

Getting good `n_distinct` estimates for more complicated queries becomes increasingly more difficult. Sometimes [extended statistics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createstatistics.html) will improve the estimate considerably.

As far as I know, PostgreSQL v12 does not bring any improvements in this area.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed comments. Regarding the complicated query voodoo at the top, I got it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250253/postgresql-countdistinct-very-slow. I did an analyze immediately before the sample query above, but have never tried adjusting the sample size, I'll dig into the docs, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Without changing the size, we can achieve this. Try running this query replace schema name and table name. Postitive values in n_distinct are actual cardinalities, for negative n_distinct, column_cardinality will fit

```
with cte as (
            select
                table_name as tablename,
                table_schema,
                (xpath('/row/cnt/text()', xml_count))[1]::text::int as row_count
            from (
                select
                    table_name,
                    table_schema,
                    query_to_xml(format('select count(*) as cnt from %I.%I', table_schema, table_name), false, true, '') as xml_count
                from information_schema.tables
                where table_schema = schemaname 
            ) t
        ) select
            a.tablename,
            a.attname as column_name,
            a.n_distinct,
            ABS(ROUND(a.n_distinct * b.row_count::numeric)) as column_cardinality
        from
            pg_stats a
            inner join cte b on a.tablename = b.tablename
        where
            a.tablename = nameoftable;
```